Can we set Java environment variables at run time in Java 17
I'm trying to set environment variables at run time using reflection in a Java application that's being migrated from Java 8 to Java 17. I'm changing the environment variable for my unit testing. Previously, in Java 8, I was able to modify environment variables using reflection to access the underlying map in Collections.unmodifiableMap.
However, after migrating to Java 17, I'm getting the following error due to the Java Platform Module System's strong encapsulation:

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Map java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module

While I know I can use --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED as a workaround, I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't require modifying JVM arguments.
I tried using the reflection approach that worked in Java 8, implemented in Kotlin:
fun setEnv(newEnv: Map<String, String>) {
    val unmodifiableMapClass = Collections.unmodifiableMap<Any, Any>(mapOf()).javaClass
    with(unmodifiableMapClass.getDeclaredField("m")) {
        isAccessible = true
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        get(System.getenv()) as MutableMap<String, String>
    }.apply {
        clear()
        putAll(newEnv)
    }
}

I expected to be able to modify environment variables at runtime, but Java 17's module system prevents access to these internal implementations with the error:

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field
private final java.util.Map java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m
accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed
module

I want to avoid using --add-opens flags as it feels like a workaround rather than a proper solution. I'm looking for a clean alternative approach that works with Java 17's security model.

IMHO no solution that accesses private internals is a clean solution (neither in Java 8 nor in Java 17). You need a clean solution for your basic problem that does not require modifying environment variables at runtime.

There is simply no "clean" way to do this. The solution depends on your use case. Why do you need this? Is it for unit testing, for setting the environment prior to spawning a subprocess, or for setting the application's environment before calling a method that uses System.getenv?

I think the enhanced strong encapsulation in Java 17 described by  JEP 403 means you can't do this at all.

why not use  System.setProperty?

In general processes can modify their own environment variables. If Java does not allow to do so you might need a small unit library that directly uses the os specific API to do so.

@Robert indeed processes can modify their own environment, and Java does not allow you to do so; but Java applications don't run in a process, they run in a virtual machine.

@k314159 And every Java Virtual Machine runs within a process (as the common OS we use like Windows, Linux, MacOS require to have a process to execute something).

@Robert that's right, but the Java application sees only a copy of the process's environment. The JRE takes the environment table from the process and creates a Java Map, and uses only the latter in System.getenv calls. See https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/eb0d1ce9487df000b4675901cc0d18f6a1c86348/src/java.base/unix/classes/java/lang/ProcessEnvironment.java#L86 and https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/eb0d1ce9487df000b4675901cc0d18f6a1c86348/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L838

@k314159 Ok, that is indeed an important detail. As DanDaDan has not told us why he/she tries to modify the ENV it is not clear if there is alternative way without modifying something that shouldn't be modified...

Java certainly does allow you to do this.  Just use System.setProperty, or System.setProperties.  These do not persist, but can be set at run-time.  You can read/save them from a config file if needed.  The environment in this case is the JVM.

@browsermator System.setProperty is for setting system properties. This question is about the environment variables.

I guess I'm thinking about "environment" variables more loosely.  I wonder about the use-case here, as the posted code would accomplish the same as setting system properties, no?

I've asked for the use case and am still waiting for a reply. I don't think we can answer this question until we know the use case.

Hey Im changing the Environment variable for my unit testing, will this enough to understand the use case, if you need more details please ask

@DanDaDan When asked for information, please add it by editing your question. Don't (only) post it in the comments. I've edited your question to add your rationale.

As mentioned by others, this doesn’t change the process environment but just Java‘s copy of the variables and even that is fragile, e.g. under Windows, System.getenv(String) does not access this map but uses a different one. It would be helpful to know more about the actual operation under test, to understand why it needs this specific hack.

Can I use this answer, will that do the same thing as what I was doing in the above code? Or will it change the environments variables for whole things instead of just testing?

The answer you mention uses environment variables set by the Surefire plugin, which is only used during unit testing. So yes, you can use that. Note, however, that you'll have those custom environment values for all your unit tests.

Yes got it, @k314159 for now its fine for me to have same value for all unit tests.

For unit testing, there are some utilities you may be able to use specifically for this purpose. They allow you to test code using a given value for a specified environment variable. For example, there is Kotest system extensions:
withEnvironment("FooKey", "BarValue") {
    System.getenv("FooKey") shouldBe "BarValue" // System environment overridden!
}

If you're not using the Kotest framework, you can use JUnit Pioneer:
@Test
@SetEnvironmentVariable(key = "some variable", value = "new value")
void testSet() {
    assertThat(System.getenv("some variable")).isEqualTo("new value");
}


JUnit Pioneer Internally uses reflections which doesn't work in Java 17 warning

@DanDaDan good point, I hadn't seen that. At least with JUnit Pioneer you can restrict your add-opens to test code only, and leave the production code secure (but then you can also do that with the code in your original question too.)
